# Issue Microservice routed to Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I've built seperately :

Eureka Server,
Spring Cloud Gateway (+ Discovery Client),
Spring Web App (+ Discovery Client)

`Eureka Server Main Class` :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceRegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and `application.yml`

```
server:
   port: 8761
   
eureka:
   client:
      fetch-registry: false
      register-with-eureka: false
```

`Gateway Main Class` :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and `application.yml`

```
server:
   port: 8080
   
spring:
   application:
      name: GATEWAY
   cloud:
      gateway:
         routes:
            -id: MICROSERVICE
            uri: lb://MICROSERVICE
            predicates:
                - Path: /service/**

         
eureka:
   client:
      register-with-eureka: true
      fetch-registry: true
      service-url: 
         defualtZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
   instance: localhost
```

`Microservice Main Class` :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MicroserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`Microservice Controller` :

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RequestMapping
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String getWelcomed() {
        return "Welcome to Microservice !";
    }
}
```

and `application.yml`

```
server:
   port: 8099

spring:
   application:
      name: MICROSERVICE
   
eureka:
   client:
      register-with-eureka: true
      fetch-registry: true
      service-url: 
         defualtZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
   instance: localhost
```

My issue now is that I can't access my microservice '/test' call through the gateway.
I keep getting this error :

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no configured error view,
> so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Dec 23 21:10:14 WEST 2020 [3c6a9e3d-9] There was an unexpected
> error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND
> at
> org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.ResourceWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ResourceWebHandler.java:325)
> Suppressed:
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Error has
> been observed at the following site(s):   |_ checkpoint ⇢
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   |_ checkpoint ⇢
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/service/test"
> [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Stack trace:        at
> org.springframework.web.reactive.resource.ResourceWebHandler.lambda$handle$0(ResourceWebHandler.java:325)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)        at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:359)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)        at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2152)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2026)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)      at
> reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)         at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)        at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> at
> reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServerHandle.java:65)
> at
> reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:518)
> at
> reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerBind$ChildObserver.onStateChange(TcpServerBind.java:278)
> at
> reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:475)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:191)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
> at
> io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)         at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

I've tried hiding the gateway from my eureka server based on some suggestions I've found, yet the issue persists by addind this to my `application.yml` in gateway :

```
eureka:
   client:
      register-with-eureka: false
      fetch-registry: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controller should be

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class HelloController
```

and the URL : http://localhost:8080/service/test

or you can leave `@RequestMapping()` in the controller and make the gateway using this path :

```
predicates:
 -Path=/**
```

then the URL should be: http://localhost:8080/test